# PHP preg_replace URL not working

Tags: php, wordpress, url, preg-replace

I have the following URL structure:

`http://website.com/wordpress/2012/04/permalink-string-string/`

I want to get rid of `/2012/04`

I tried this:

`$cont = preg_replace('http:\\/\\/website\\/.com\\/wordpress\\/[0-9]{4}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/', 'http://website.com/', $cont);`

I double-escaped the backslash...

I tried samples from other topics and not getting any result. Just empty `$cont`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had one extra `/`, didn't have starting and ending slashes and you never escaped the dot which means that it could accept anything in the place of the dot. However, here's the working code:

```
$cont = "http://website.com/wordpress/2012/04/permalink-string-string/";
$cont = preg_replace('/http:\/\/website\.com\/wordpress\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\//', 'http://website.com/', $cont);
print_r($cont);
```

This prints `http://website.com/permalink-string-string/`

Comment: Thanks, but in your example code, it works, but for my $cont, wich is a long HTML code, it does not replace...

Comment: in fact, IT WORKS! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could probably be simplified a bit with a negative lookahead assertion

```
$cont = preg_replace('/.*?\/(?!.*\/)/', 'http://www.website.com/wordpress/', $cont);
```

That'll fetch everything up to the last instance of a forward slash.